# zoom in / zoom out jquery code not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Introduction --** I have a webpage containing a large image and 2 buttons - 'move next' & 'move previous'.Also, the image can be zoomed in or zoomed out using jquery zoom code from (http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smart-jQuery-Pan-Zoom-Plugin-Smart-jQuery-Zoom/example/).

**What i want from the code -** When the webpage loads for the first time, i should be able to zoomin/zoom out the image.Also when i click the 'move next' or 'move previous' buttons, the newly dynamically loaded image should have the ability to be zoomed in/zoomed out.

**The current problem -** At present my webpage is working perfectly, except the image zoom in/zoom out part when the 'move next' or 'move previous' buttons are clicked.When the page is loaded for the 1st time, image can be zoomed in/zoomed out but not when 'move next' or 'move previous' buttons are clicked.

**Code -**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#big_pg_img").smartZoom(); // where #big_pg_img = id of the image
    });
</script>

<script>
    function gotoNextPage(){//--> NEXT
        var currPage = document.getElementById('curr_pg').value;
        var nextPage = parseInt(currPage)+1;
        var totPages = document.getElementById('tot_pgs').value;

        var edId = document.getElementById('edition_id').value;
        var pgId = document.getElementById('page_id').value;
        var img_ele = "#img_"+nextPage;

        if(parseInt(currPage) < parseInt(totPages)){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/load_req_page_via_navigator/"+edId+"/"+parseInt(nextPage)+"/"+0,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(msg){
                    $('#big_pg_img').smartZoom({'containerClass':'zoomableContainer'});
                    //alert('2');

                    $("#slider1_container").html(msg);
                    for(i=1;i<=totPages;i++)
                    {
                        var img_ele_old = "#img_"+i;
                        $(img_ele_old).removeClass("selected");
                    }
                    $(img_ele).addClass("selected");
                    $("#page_thumb_container").scrollTo('.selected');
                },
                error: function(result)
                {
                    //alert('e');
                    $("#slider1_container").html("Error");
                },
                fail:(function(status) {
                    //alert('f');
                    $("#slider1_container").html("Fail");
                })
            });
        }else if(parseInt(currPage) == parseInt(totPages)){
            alert('This is the Last Page');
        }
    }

    function gotoPreviousPage(){//<-- PREVIOUS
        var currPage = document.getElementById('curr_pg').value;
        var startPage = 1;
        var prevPage = parseInt(currPage)-1;
        var totPages = document.getElementById('tot_pgs').value;

        var edId = document.getElementById('edition_id').value;
        var pgId = document.getElementById('page_id').value;
        var img_ele = "#img_"+prevPage;

        if(parseInt(currPage) > parseInt(startPage)){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/load_req_page_via_navigator/"+edId+"/"+parseInt(prevPage)+"/"+0,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(msg){
                    $('#big_pg_img').smartZoom({'containerClass':'zoomableContainer'});
                    //alert('3');

                    $("#slider1_container").html(msg);
                    for(i=1;i<=totPages;i++)
                    {
                        var img_ele_old = "#img_"+i;
                        $(img_ele_old).removeClass("selected");
                    }
                    $(img_ele).addClass("selected");
                    $("#page_thumb_container").scrollTo('.selected');
                },
                error: function(result)
                {
                    //alert('e');
                    $("#slider1_container").html("Error");
                },
                fail:(function(status) {
                    //alert('f');
                    $("#slider1_container").html("Fail");
                })
            });
        }else if(parseInt(currPage) == parseInt(startPage)){
            alert('This is the First Page');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please advise whats wrong with my code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somebody please answer my query

Comment: Can you provide us with jsfiddle of your code